# i want to create a user form that can buy multiple products

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to create a market program that can be used by users to buy items. I have written the following code but it is giving me a problem which I am not able to fix. If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

The code has the following functionality: (see [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIKZp.png))
the user buys a product and this information is saved in a table of a database.

But there is a problem: (see [database pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcYiA.png))
information about the purchase is not saved in the user field but another field is created.

Can anybody please help me?

```
 private void User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            conect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conect;
            command.CommandText = "select * from Item ";

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                combo.Items.Add(reader["Item_Name"].ToString());

            }
            conect.Close();


    }

    private void combo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conect;
            command.CommandText = "select * from Item where Item_Name='"+combo.Text+"'";
            conect.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                item_id.Text = reader["Item_ID"].ToString();

                Price.Text = reader["Item_Price"].ToString();



            }
            conect.Close();


    }




    private void Buy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            conect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conect;
                command.CommandText = "insert into Sign_Up ([Item_Name],[Price]) values ('" + combo.Text + "','" + Price.Text + "')";

        if (combo.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Chose An Item");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conect.Close();
        }




    }
```

Comment: It looks like you need to redesign your database - you are adding items purchased into the "Sign_Up" table. I would expect that table to only contain the user's details - at the very least you would have a separate table for items ordered - the items purchased could be grouped together using an order number & each item would also be linked back to the user by having a foreign key field containing the user ID. (NOTE there are much better ways to design the database - but they can be difficult to understand for a beginner)

Comment: @PaulF i don't know much about data base linking 
i created a another one just for the items but i was not able to link so i leave it 
is there are any tutorials that will help me on that

Comment: Plenty if you search online - you can search for both basic tutorials in relational database design or specific to MS_Access - I just found this one on the Microsoft site : https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/database-design-basics-eb2159cf-1e30-401a-8084-bd4f9c9ca1f5

Comment: @Johnwiliam please read [ask]! We do not recomend any external tutorials as they tend to create discussions.

Comment: @PaulF thanks i will try to do it thanks